# BigQuery recursive calculated column

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to create a calculated column using data from a table. This calculated column (x_average) is based on the application of a formula for calculating an average, where the next value of "x_average" needs the previous value of that same calculated column. I ended up calling this a recursive calculation because the next value needs the previous value. The formula is somewhat similar to the following:

```
x_average =  (days + (x_average * stock)) 
            -----------------------------
                 (input + stock)
```

The table is similar to the following example:

```
+-----------------------------------+
+ date       | days | input | stock + 
+-----------------------------------+
+ 2020-01-03 | 11   |  5    |  5    +
+ 2020-01-05 | 3    |  1    |  2    +
+ 2020-01-15 | 21   |  7    |  1    +
+ 2020-01-16 | 17   |  12   |  4    +
+ 2020-01-22 | 15   |  4    |  3    +
+ (more...)
+-----------------------------------+
```

How to create a query that can select the table and the calculated column (x_average)?

The expected result is similar to:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
+ date       | days | input | stock | x_average + 
+-----------------------------------------------+
+ 2020-01-03 | 11   |  5    |  5    |    1.1    +
+ 2020-01-05 | 3    |  1    |  2    |    1.733  +
+ 2020-01-15 | 21   |  7    |  1    |    2.841  +
+ 2020-01-16 | 17   |  12   |  4    |    1.772  +
+ 2020-01-22 | 15   |  4    |  3    |    2.902  +
+ (more...)
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

The table can be between 1 and 365 rows.

Comment: vote done, thank you

Comment: few questions: 1. how big table is (in terms of rows count) 2. the should be some extra field that would define the order in which to process rows - do you have the row in your table that can be used for this ? if not you must add it!!!

Comment: 1. from 1 to 365 rows
2. the date

Comment: ok. adding date makes sense - but requires them to be distinct so no rows with the same date! also just 300 rows or so, makes it open to quite a number of easy approaches. I will take a look at it when time allows - unless someone else will jump sooner :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and uses scripting functionality of BQ

```
#standardSQL
declare a, b, c array<float64>;
declare i, len int64;

/*
create temp table input_table as
  select '2020-01-03' date, 11 days, 5 input , 5 stock union all
  select '2020-01-05', 3, 1, 2 union all
  select '2020-01-15', 21, 7, 1 union all
  select '2020-01-16', 17, 12, 4 union all
  select '2020-01-22', 15, 4, 3; 
*/

set (i, len, c, a, b) = (
  select as struct 1, count(1), [1.0],
    array_agg(days / (input + stock) order by date), 
    array_agg(stock / (input + stock) order by date)
  from input_table
);

while i <= len do 
  if i = 1 then set c = [round(a[ordinal(i)], 3)]; 
    else set c = c || [a[ordinal(i)] + c[ordinal(i - 1)] * b[ordinal(i)]];
  end if;
  set i = i + 1;
end while;

create temp table output as
select * except(i), round(c[ordinal(i)], 3) as x_average
from (
  select *, row_number() over(order by date) i
  from input_table
);

select * from output order by date;
```

when you run it (against your table - input_table - or you can uncomment temp table portion to do testing with dummy data from your question) you get something like below

[image]

click on <kbd>VIEW RESULTS</kbd> on the very last row to see resulted table - output

[image]

Note: As I mentioned in my comments  - there are quite a number of ways to implement your logic  - but I've chose one using scripting. You can experiment with JS UDF for example  - should be easy exercise base on code in above script

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. I had solved this problem using something similar as its answer, through arrays and loopings, inside a script. But what I wonder is whether it is possible to solve this problem using only SELECTs, without using looping with "WHILEs", "LOOPs", "ARRAYs", etc. A solution where one (or more) SELECTs using (or not) window functions, could solve the "recursive" calculation

Comment: Also, I had already made another solution where the looping part was done inside a JS UDF, but how can I solve it without using scripting and JS? Is possible?

Comment: Other databases allow 'Recursive CTEs' which would be a good solution as a standalone query (without scripting), which is what I think you're asking for.  However, BQ does not support that (yet).

Comment: @ClaytonBonelli - consider voting up the answer if it was helpful and accept, meantime to address your desire of not using script and making it in pure set based approach - I think it is possible in this particular case  - but practically speaking what the reason to spend time to come up with tricky solution if there is relatively easy way to do it with script or js udf? but again - I think it is doable!

Comment: My goal was to see if it is possible and if the solution would be very complex or not, it would also be an opportunity to learn a new trick with SQL that allows to solve this particular problem.